# How to locate or work with different locator in selemium webdrier frameowrk?

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am beginner in selenium webdriver, I am trying to work with different locator by reading excel sheet but in these it take only one data put it in one field by finding locator "id", and when it come to the second text field for this we are using locator by "Xpath" but its not taking. So, my question is how can I work with different locator also by don't using switch case if possible.
Below are my code:

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final String BROWSER_PATH = "D:\\firefox.exe";
    private static final String TEST_SUITE_PATH = "D:\\GmailTestSuite.xls";
    private static final String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH = "D:\\objectrepository.xls";
    private static final String ADDRESS_TO_TEST = "https://www.gmail.com";

    // other constants

    private WebDriver driver;
    private Properties properties;
    /*private WebElement we;*/

    public MainClass() {
        File file = new File(BROWSER_PATH);
        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(file);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(fb, new FirefoxProfile());
        driver.get(ADDRESS_TO_TEST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        main.handleTestSuite();
    }

    private void handleTestSuite() throws BiffException, IOException {
        ReadPropertyFile readConfigFile = new ReadPropertyFile();
        properties = readConfigFile.loadPropertiess();

        ExcelHandler testSuite = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH, "Suite");
        testSuite.columnData();

        int rowCount = testSuite.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows=" + rowCount);

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String executable = testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("Executable"), i);
            System.out.println("Executable=" + executable);

            if (executable.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                // exe. the process
                String scenarioName = testSuite.readCell(testSuite.getCell("TestScenario"), i);
                System.out.println("Scenario Name=" + scenarioName);
                handleScenario(scenarioName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleScenario(String scenarioName) throws BiffException, IOException {
        ExcelHandler testScenarios = new ExcelHandler(TEST_SUITE_PATH);
        testScenarios.setSheetName("Login");
        testScenarios.columnData();
        int rowWorkBook1 = testScenarios.rowCount();
        for (int j = 1; j < rowWorkBook1; j++) {
            String framWork = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("FrameworkName"), j);
            String operation = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Operation"), j); // SendKey
            String value = testScenarios.readCell(testScenarios.getCell("Value"), j);
            System.out.println("FRMNameKK=" + framWork + ",Operation=" + operation +
                               ",Value=" + value);

            handleObjects(operation,value,framWork);
        }
    }

    private void handleObjects(String operation,String value,String framWork) throws BiffException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("HandleObject--> "+framWork);
        ExcelHandler objectRepository = new ExcelHandler(OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH, "OR");
        objectRepository.columnData();
        int rowCount = objectRepository.rowCount();
        System.out.println("Total Rows in hadleObject=" + rowCount);

        for (int k = 1; k < rowCount; k++) {
            String frameWorkName = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("FrameworkName"), k);
            String ObjectName = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("ObjectName"), k);
            String Locator = objectRepository.readCell(objectRepository.getCell("Locator"), k); // SendKey

            System.out.println("FrameWorkNameV=" + frameWorkName +
                               ",ObjectName=" + ObjectName + ",Locator=" + Locator);


            if(framWork.equalsIgnoreCase(frameWorkName))
            {   
                    operateWebDriver(operation,Locator,value,ObjectName);

            }       
        }
    }

    private void operateWebDriver(String operation,String Locator,String value, String objectName) 
    {
        System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
        WebElement temp=getElement(Locator,objectName);
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) 
        {                   
            temp.sendKeys(value);            
        } 
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) 
        {        
            temp.click();            
        }
    }


    public WebElement getElement(String locator,String objectName)
    {
        WebElement temp = null;
        if(locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
        {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));
        }else if(locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {

            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName)); 
        }       
        if(locator.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
        {

        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not clear what exactly the problem is. Do you need to get rid of if else structure in your getElement method ? Or the xpath locator is not working in your getElement method ?

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq Actually with this code I am able to get all the locators but when I run the programme it take the value whose locator "id" and put that value in text field but not taking other locators value. So, I want to know how can I work with different locator at same time?

Comment: So you are not able to run the locators of different type. Have you checked if you are able to read it properly from property file and even you have it configured properly in property file ?

Can you please print the values retrieved in **handleScenario()** and **handleObjects()** method to check if you are getting locator values correctly from property file ?

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq Yes I am able to read workbook properly and in handleScenario() it get value=(id=37) and in handleObjects() it get for "operation" value=(id=40), "value" value=(id=42), framework it get value=(id=44).

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq waiting for your reply.

Comment: I guess I am have not understood your question completely. What do you mean when you say **text field for this we are using locator by "Xpath" but its not taking** ? Can you please describe your exact problem please.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq leave all this just see my code and tell me where I am going wrong. 
Actually, I want to know how we can work with different locators in framework, and all this locator written in the excel sheet that's why I am declaring locator as a string.

Comment: Check this link http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=388 . It has examples of all the locators which can be used to get the element. As you are able to read the locator details from excel file you can prepare the if else ladder to identify correct locator and execute that locator code accordingly.

I wanted to have more information on your question as I am still not sure what exactly is required but I have tried to give you information related to your question/comment.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq May I know where you have an doubt?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Reflection. See example in 2 methods below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
...
@Test
public void TestAmazon() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.amazon.com");

    String locatorType = "id";
    String locatorExpression = "twotabsearchtextbox";           

    By locator = createLocator(locatorType, locatorExpression);                 
    WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(locator);
    textbox.sendKeys("Star Wars: The Digital Movie Collection");
    textbox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    locatorType = "className";
    locatorExpression = "nav-logo-link";
    locator = createLocator(locatorType, locatorExpression);    
    driver.findElement(locator).click();
}


private By createLocator(String locatorType, final String locatorExpression) {
    By locator = null;
    Class<By> byClass = By.class;
    Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String.class };
    try {
        Method m = byClass.getDeclaredMethod(locatorType, argTypes);

        try {
            locator = (By)m.invoke(null,locatorExpression);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return locator;
}
```